# Give Notification To Android Application When MySQL Database's Table Has New Entry

Tags: php, android, mysql

So, I am a Android Developer and now a day working with MySQL Database. But during that my requirement is to Give Notification to Android application user when there is any Newer entry into the table.

Like when any raw is added into the table if it related to that particular user than if provided the notification from android application.

Now, I know that track of newly inserted raw is created by the **Database/Table Triggers** but I don't know how to use triggers with Android application.

Till Now I had worked with Android+ Php + MySQL combinations.

Note : - I am working with android studio with java.

Thank You for support

Comment: You really do not want to go down the trigger route. It is clunky and relies on compiled UDFs to send notifications back. I have seen studies about such solutions, but have not heard that anyone would have tried it in a real-life application.

Comment: database triggers are completely useless in this scenario, since they won't run PHP code.

Comment: @MartinZeitler well, they can through a compiled UDF...

Comment: I'd really suggest finding a way to write this app to not require this.  This is one of those things that works great with a dozen or so users, and falls apart at any type of real scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option available is something alike server-side [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) Firebase Cloud Messaging.

So that the PHP method, which inserts the record, also will push the notification. You can try it with the [API Explorer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send), so that you'll reliably know, how the [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request has to look alike. Any push-notification service should work, while one can post notification messages on the server-side.

Alternatively, (unless depending on SQL-specific features) you could use the  [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), which supports notification about new records by default - and this would subsequently permit sending a local notification and/or updating an adapter.